# коллизия в Box2d

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

изучаю LibGDX и использую физический движок Box2d, может кто-то подсказать как создать столкновения предметов (персонажа, который движется и стоячего камня), или же дать ссылку на какой-либо хороший, актуальный гайд, потому что все, что я пересмотрел я не смог применить у себя. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

А в чём собственно проблема в самой программе? В самом простом случае никаких обработчиков не нужно, `DynamicBody` сталкивается с предметами (в данном случае `StaticBody`) по умолчанию. В остальных же ситуациях нужно использовать `world.setContactListener()` и специальные методы, которые возвращают контактирующие тела, вся необходимая информация есть в документации на гитхабе для libgdx: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki